# Capturing brightness on IR Camera in daylight

Tags: brightness

I am wondering if an IR camera (or a camera with IR-cut) can capture the brightness of a retro reflective tape (high grade SOLAS) on screen in broad daylight. Since the main goal is to capture brightness, you are more than welcome to suggest other supplements to achieve this goal (IR LEDs, filters, lenses etc.) as long as they are not visible to human eye.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you talking about *measuring* brightness, *detecting* the tape by computer-vision or some other algorithm, or whether an IR camera can *see* reflective tape in daylight?

Comment: I would say both detecting the tape by computer-vision and checking if an IR camera can see reflective tape brightly in daylight. I am planning to use it as a control mechanism over my tracking algorithm.

Comment: Also, is this for an actual SOLAS application, or on less reflective dry land?

Comment: It isn't clear to me that you understand that reflective tape will appear bright to the image sensor ONLY if there's a bright source of light co-located with the sensor. In ambient light, even bright daylight, it does not stand out at all.

Comment: you should modulate the IR light, but really the image capture rate of the camera is so slow and so quantized that you will not be able to differentiate properly between natural sunlight IR and an emitted/unnatural IR light.

Comment: This is pretty much what I am trying to achieve: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LFHnb.jpg (about 35-40 feet distance)

Answer (score 1):

If by IR you mean Near IR (NIR) and if by IR camera you mean a camera that can see into the NIR (with it's IR cut filter *removed*) then yes.  In fact there are licensee plate readers that are based upon a IR emitting source and a standard Si based image sensor (CCD or otherwise) that work very well.  In fact the NIR is chosen for usability, lack of distractibility of the driver and the fact that the retro reflective beads in the license plate paint reflect the light.

You will need to test each camera individually as the NIR response varies so much.